# Условный JOIN-таблиц в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Данные тянутся с таблицы **question**, далее следуют JOIN's

Нужно, чтобы при **question.category > 0** был:

```
LEFT JOIN detailtousers b
          ON b.idDetailToUsers = a.QuestionIdUser
```

В противном случае, другой **JOIN**

Нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
IF a.QuestionToUser > 0 THEN
      LEFT JOIN detailtousers c
          ON c.idDetailToUsers = a.QuestionToUser
      ELSEIF a.QuestionToUser = 0 THEN
      LEFT JOIN detailtousers c
          ON c.idDetailToUsers = d.AnswerToQuestionIdUser
      ENDIF
```

Comment: даже если бы так можно было написать, то какие данные вы ожидаете получить в выборке? этакий дырявый куб вместо таблицы?

Comment: Я лишь привел пример

Comment: в том-то и дело, что вы не привели никакого примера. вы очень приблизительно описали какую-то свою мысль, но не довели ее до конца. я еще раз попрошу объяснить какие данные вы ожидаете увидеть в выборке? получить одним запросом разнородные данные можно несколькими способами, но гадать какой вам вариант подойдет желания нет. учитывая ваши предыдущие вопросы, в которых большинство отвечающих гадает на кофейной гуще, вы либо сами не понимаете что вам надо и принимаете ответы по количеству "умных слов", либо (более вероятно) у вас неверный подход к структурам данных и их обработке, кои надо менят

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно поступают следующим образом: JOIN-ят все три таблицы, учитывая что у вас `LEFT JOIN` вы особо ничего не теряете - количество записей в промежуточной таблице определяется `question`. А вот уже в конструкции `SELECT` выводят записи в зависимости от значения поля `question.category`

```
SELECT
  a.QuestionIdUser,
  IF(a.category > 0, b.number, c.number) AS number
FROM
  question a
LEFT JOIN
  detailtousers b
ON
  b.idDetailToUsers = a.QuestionIdUser
LEFT JOIN
  detailtousers c
ON
  c.idDetailToUsers = a.QuestionIdUser
```